# Upon expiracy, remove the entry from Guava Cache and LoadingCache

Tags: guava

I am trying to use Guava cache in my project, and I investigate Guava Cache and LoadingCache.

I am using following code to create the cache:

```
     Cache<Person, Integer> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterAccess(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();


cache.get(key, CallableProvidedForLoading)
```

or

```
final LoadingCache<Person, Integer> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .maximumSize(100)
        .expireAfterAccess(6, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .expireAfterWrite(6, TimeUnit.SECONDS) 
        .build(
                new CacheLoader<Person, Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public Integer load(Person key) throws Exception {
                        //can't return null, use -1 to indicate invalid value
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
        );
```

What I want to achieve is that, if the entry is not accessed for a period, for example,10 minute, then remove this entry from the cache.

But if looks to me that the Cache and LoadingCache will try to reload the entry if time expires,this will keep this entry stay in the cache even it will not be used any more.

So,I would ask how to remove the entry from cache upon expiry

Comment: The cache will evict the entry and, if the key is then queried for, it will call the loading function again to fetch it. It will not proactively fetch entries if they are expired or inactive. However, expiration is lazily amortized on calls so the entry will remain (but mimic'd as a miss) until the next maintenance cycle. You can use `cleanUp` in test code to force one.

Comment: Thanks @BenManes.What do you mean by `until the next maintenance cycle`,

Comment: Instead of locking and updating the policy data structures immediately, the reads are recorded and replayed in batches. Thus, after enough reads or a write, a segment’s pending work is performed. This improves performance and simplifies the concurrency logic.

Comment: Thanks @BenManes